# import error in python

Tags: python, python-import

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myemail.py", line 1, in <module>
  import smtplib
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
  import email.utils
File "/home/nikhil/Desktop/bujji/email.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MIMEMultipart
```

when i run the [code example](http://kutuma.blogspot.com/2007/08/sending-emails-via-gmail-with-python.html)

I tried to google out the error but nothing worked.

Answer (score 66):

You've stomped on the `email` package in the stdlib by naming a script `email.py`. Rename it.

Comment: so simple yet hard to realize!

Comment: Good call! I wouldn't have spotted this.

Comment: don't forget to also remove email.pyc if one was created.

Answer (score 11):

Don't have enough reputation to comment on Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer but make sure that not only do you remove email.py put also things like email.py~ and email.pyc

Answer (score 7):

The package names have changed. I believe that the new name is `email.mime.multipart`.

Just adapt your imports to import `email.mime.multipart` instead of `email.MIMEMultipart`.

Also, be aware that `email.MIMEBase` is now `email.mime.base` and `email.MIMEText` is now `email.mime.text`.

Comment: In Python 2.6, the module is `email.mime.multipart`, the class is `email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart`.

Comment: Except `smtplib` is the one importing from the `email` package here.