# Inconsistent import result

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror, smtplib

When I enter a python environment from my home directory and try to `import smtplib` I get the following error:

```
>>> import smtplib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "email.py", line 3, in <module>
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
ImportError: No module named mime.text
```

My `which python` for my home directory is `/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/bin/python`. The strange thing is that I can successfully import smtplib from `/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/lib/python2.7` even though my `which python` is the same as in my home directory. How can I get an error in the former but not in the latter if my path/`which python` doesn't change?

Comment: Most probably you have an `email.py` in your `home` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971085/import-error-in-python) to me.

Don't you have any python script in your home directory (***email.py*** in the previous link) overwriting some package ? If so, rename it.